# Car with rebuilt engine cracked after driving 3,000 miles

Tags: engine, oil, oil-change, lights, rebuild

I bought a used 2004 Hyundai Sonata with 120K miles that had a rebuilt engine.  When I bought the car, I noticed the oil light would turn on and would stay on if the car was idling.  The mechanic who sold me the car said it was not an issue.  There was no oil leak.

After a while, about 500 miles the oil light would come on.  I took it to another mechanic who mentioned there was no oil in the car. He did an oil change for me every 2 weeks.  There was no visible oil leak or dirty exhaust.

Well, after 3,000 miles, the car stalled after going up a hill.  The original mechanic who sold me the car will not honor the warranty since he says I went to another mechanic for an oil change and says it is his fault.    I told him how he dismissed the oil light when I bought the car, but he still places the blame on me.

What should I do?  Also, how can I discuss where the problem started?

Comment: This is really a legal matter. If you have paperwork showing a limited warranty, take the original mechanic to court and get it fixed through the legal system. Because it's a legal matter, this really isn't on-topic for this SE site.

Comment: Just beware of "rebuilt" engines. It's so easy to get one tiny little thing wrong, and the engine kills itself. Besides, lots of people don't really know what "rebuilt" means, and use the term loosely to increase to perceived value of a vehicle before selling it. The oil light is warning about a low oil pressure, which is often due to a low oil amount.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for legal advice